# JavaScript String.split(): Split by ; that is NOT preceded by a Backslash?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I need to split a string by every ; that is NOT escaped (that is preceded by 0, 2, 4, 6 etc. Backslashes).

There already are several threads about this issue, but I didn't find anything that worked for me. Each regex I tried either gave an error or split the string not at any valid delimeter or split it not at all.

```
"statement1(); statement2('\;');".split(/(\\.;[^;])+/g)
```

This e. g. just returned [ 'statement1(); statement2(\';\');' ].
Any other idea?

Comment: The input string given does not actually have any literal backslashes in it. Does your actual input contain backslashes?

Comment: Can you provide some input examples and the expected result?

Comment: Strings with backslashes in them evaluate before they are executed on. If that's in an input value, it will be a literal backslash. otherwise the String would have to have `\\\` in it to represent a single backslash.

Comment: Off topic probably, but are you sure you also want to split on (unescaped) semicolons that are in quotes?

Comment: Thank you @MrLister for this point, I really fogot that! I guess, I will not use any regex, instead I will write a simple `for`-loop that loopes through every character and splits the statements. Less elegant, but it should work :)

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem using a lookbehind assertion:

```
/(?<=[^\\]);/
```

should do what you need. It says match `;` preceded by a character which is not `\`.

In a different programming language, I would have used a negative lookbehind assertion, but only very recent versions of JavaScript support it, so it's safer to write it as a positive lookbehind assertion instead, as above.

Comment: This did not worked for me: `"s1; s2(\;)".split(/(?<=[^\\]);/)` created output `['s1', 's2(', ')']`...

Comment: I found an alternative, see my comment above

Comment: Sounds good. If you solved your problem, that's what matters.